# Moving Data from one Column to another, based on a condition

Tags: pandas, formula, move

I'm trying to move data from one column to another.
data = {'Name':['Kauto Star', 'Denman', 'Frankel', 'Desert Orchid'], 'Result':['W', 'L', 'W', 'p'], 'Winning Odds': [4, 5, 6, 7]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

Results in

```
        Name Result  Winning Odds
```

0     Kauto Star      W             4
1         Denman      L             5
2        Frankel      W             6
3  Desert Orchid      P             7

Where the result is showing a 'W' I want to move the value in Winning Odds over to the results column, and replace the 'L' or 'P' with -1.

I tried this code first to move the number from 'Winning Odds' Over

df['Result'] =np.where((df['Result'] == 'W'), df['Result'], df['Winning Odds'])

It returned

```
        Name Result  Winning Odds
```

0     Kauto Star      W             4
1         Denman      5             5
2        Frankel      W             6
3  Desert Orchid      7             7

I want the final table to look Like

```
        Name Result  Winning Odds
```

0     Kauto Star      4             4
1         Denman      -1            5
2        Frankel      6             6
3  Desert Orchid      -1            7

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` function to replace values in the result column

```
df['Result'] = np.where(df['Result']=='W', df['Winning Odds'], -1)
```

The way np.where function works is, if it meets the criteria (which in our case is if result == 'W'), use the first value (df['winning odds']). If not, use the second value (-1).